# XSD to Java POJO, it created a custom String class

Tags: json, xsd, jaxb, pojo, hl7-fhir

So, I have many XSD files defining a health-related specifications. They come from here.
https://www.hl7.org/fhir/downloads.html

I generate some Java POJO using JAXB, in eclipse but it would be the same from the command line with the xic command.

The problem I have got is that it created 700+ classes including some for the very basic java type.

Instead of linking with the `java.lang.String` class, it would create a new `org.hl7.fhir.String` class instead. 
that class would have a "value" field with a normal `String` in it.

so when I want to use my object, I would end up with that sort of convoluted code. `my object.getCode().getValue()`.
It seems to do that for `String` and also for `Boolean`.

It's not only inconvenient, it means that when i try to marshall/unmarshall corresponding json object, they have to comply to that extra nested level.

Using something horrible like this

```
{
  "id": {"value":"example-search"},
  "event": {
    "type": {
      "system": {"value":"http://hl7.org/fhir/audit-event-type"},
      "code": {"value":"rest"},
      "display": {"value":"Restful Operation"}
    },...
```

instead of the much cleaner.

```
{
  "id": "example-search",
  "event": {
    "type": {
      "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/audit-event-type",
      "code": "rest",
      "display": "Restful Operation"
    },...
```

any idea? Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the same downloads page, you can also grab the Java reference implementation.  The reference implementations are tuned to make interacting with simple types more natural, to use language conventions for getters, setters, etc.  As a bonus, they'll support parsing and serializing the JSON as well.  We designed the FHIR schemas so that you *can* generate code from the schemas, but the reference implementations will give you a much better experience.

Comment: that sounds great and much better than generating ourselves. One potential problem is how to annotate those Resource classes. Let's say I want to work with the Patient class and do some fine-tuning with java annotations to fit our other requirements. Could I for example hide the gender with @JsonIgnore and add some name validation with @Pattern(regex)? All placed on the overriden relevant getters in MWPatient, a subclass of ca.uhn.fhir.model.dstu2.resource.Patient? Many Thanks

Comment: Hi Mikael, if you just don't want to use some fields (e.g. the gender field) you don't need to. The HAPI Parser (serializer) won't encode the gender field if you don't put a value there. You can also subclass the Patient class if you want- there is no need to mark something as ignored because of the previous part, but you could override and deprocate methods if you want to mark them as unneeded.